# Функции, возвращающие указатель на функцию

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, конечные-автоматы

Нужно написать функцию ф1, которая передает управление ф2, ф2 передает управление ф3 и т.д. Знаю, как написать одну функцию, передающую указатель на функцию, но при по пытке перенести это на множественный случай - invalid conversion.

Comment: а зачем тут вообще указатели на функцию? Если функции заранее известны.

Comment: чтобы функция полностью завершалась, прежде чем передать управлние

Comment: а чем вам указатель поможет? грубо говоря в `main` пишите `f1(); f2(); f3()` ну по вашему вопросу так выходит.

Comment: может, действительно, нет смысла использовать указатели, но когда так вызывать функции:
    void f3() { }
    void f2() { f3 }
    void f1() { f2; }

    int main()
    {
        f1();
    }
программа виснет

Comment: См. мой ответ - видите там после f2 и иде с ними скобочки? Которые говорят о том, что это **вызов** функции? Вот их добавляйте... `void f3() { } void f2() { f3(); } void f1() { f2(); } int main() { f1(); }`

Comment: я ставлю, просто сюда так напечатал с ошибкой

Comment: Тогда приведите свой не работающий исходник; понять, что у вас творится, никак не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то при любой болезни желательно описывать симптомы, а не "что-то болит". Приведите свой исходник - будет понятнее, что вы хотите, и что у вас не получается. Потому что пока - остается только гадать...

Например -

```
void f3() { cout << "In f3\n"; }
void f2() { cout << "In f2\n"; f3(); }
void f1() { cout << "In f1\n"; f2(); }

int main()
{
    f1();
}
```

Это? Если нет - то поясните конкретнее, пожалуйста, с исходником - и в чем у вас с ним проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сказал, Вам нужно что-то типа такого:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef int (*F2) ();
typedef F2 (*F1) ();
typedef F1 (*F0) ();

int f2() { cout << "f2" << endl; return 1; }
F2 f1() { cout << "f1" << endl; return f2; }
F1 f0() { cout << "f0" << endl; return f1; }

int main()
{
    F0 pf0 = f0;
    F1 pf1 = pf0();
    F2 pf2 = pf1();
    int x = pf2();
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```